# stange behaviour of hplaserjet pro MFP M427fdw when OS upgraded to 22.04

Tags: printing

While trying to print pdf file my printer only printer pages with the following written on it:

URP Error

Subsystem: PARSER

Error: InternalOverflow or Insufficient Memory

File Name: urp_urf_proces

Line Number: 743

I have recently upgraded to UBUNTU 22.04...

My printer HP LaserJet Pro MFP M427fdw is connected as network printer via ethernet...

it seems that it can be printed using hp software however direct printing from pdf is not working...

it is really cumbersome to every time open a software and then upload the file and print...

Comment: have you tried in `Settings > Printers` turning your printer on and clicking `Add Printer...`

Comment: Yes...I have first done that to get the URP error...then only I installed hplip to somehow manage the print via hp device manager...but I still can not get the direct print out...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by remove the original printer, then add a new one from multiple printers with the correct IP listed one. It seems to be the IP error.

Comment: did you set a static IP in the printer setings